# How can i omit a url so i reach the url i want

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

hi i have a Form an the action method is 'Home_Search' i want to reach the Home_Search view but when ever i Post something the url will be like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/Home_Search`
and Page not found error will be raised , is there any method so i can exclude /home from the url?Only for this Form...

my url.Py :

```
path("home/", views.home, name="home"),
path("Home_Search/", views.Home_Search, name="Home_Search"),
```

and my Form is :

`<form action="Home_Search" method="post" role="form">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an *absolute* url with a leading slash, so:

```
<form action="/Home_Search/" method="post" role="form">
    …
</form>
```

but it is better to work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to determine the reverse URL:

```
<form action="{% url 'Home_Search' %}" method="post" role="form">
    …
</form>
```

URLs however often tend to have *no* uppercase characters. It thus might be better to rewrite the path to `home-search/`.